# Sub-string extraction. Get the string before last '/'

Tags: php, string, substring

I am trying to extract a sub-string. I need some help with doing it in PHP.

Here are some sample strings I am working with and the results I need:

```
$temp = "COM1904150001","1","ytuaioeighalk","tyueiff","assets/report/celc_coba/d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052/"
```

And the result i need is:

```
$temp = d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052
```

I want to get the string at my last '/'

So far, I've tried:

```
substr($temp, 0, strpos($temp, '/'))
```

But, it seems didn't work at all.

Is there a way to handle that case with PHP approach ?

Comment: This is a poor problem statement. While examples are very welcome to illustrate a problem they should support a specific  description of the problem you are trying to solve. Your description is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr()` to extract the data, but using [`strrpos()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) instead to find the last `/` position (you have to remove the trailing `/` to do this though)

```
$temp = "assets/report/celc_coba/d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052/";
// Trim off trailing / or "
$temp = rtrim($temp, "/\"");
// Return from the position of the last / (+1) to the end of the string
$temp = substr($temp, strrpos($temp, '/')+1);
echo $temp;
```

gives...

```
d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `explode()` and `end()` functions.

**Steps Explained:**

1) Explode() the string by `/`

2) Replace double quotes `"`.

3) `array_filter()` to remove blank elements.

4) `end()` for the last element as `/` and empty element after last `/` are already removed.

**Code:**

```
<?php 
$temp = '"COM1904150001","1","ytuaioeighalk","tyueiff","assets/report/celc_coba/d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052/"';
$temp = str_replace('"', '', $temp);
$url = explode('/', $temp);
$url = array_filter($url);
$requiredSegment = end($url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($requiredSegment);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052
```

[See it live here:](https://3v4l.org/i8nBK)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this code snippet

```
$temp = '"COM1904150001","1","ytuaioeighalk","tyueiff","assets/report/celc_coba/d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052/"';
$temp = rtrim(str_replace('celc_coba/','',strstr($temp, 'celc_coba/')), "/\"")
```

Result

```
d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:`explode`

```
$str = '"COM1904150001","1","ytuaioeighalk","tyueiff","assets/report/celc_coba/d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052/"';
$pieces = explode("/", $str );
```

example

```
$str = '"COM1904150001","1","ytuaioeighalk","tyueiff","assets/report/celc_coba/d02c25b2-5c07-11e9-8f1a-02fd8bf7d052/"';

$pieces = explode("/", $str );

print_r($pieces);


$count= count($pieces);


echo  $pieces[$count-2];
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/Ogiw1Pal)